# find out if AS3's XMLList contains string as node value

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, e4x, indexof

Is there an XMLList equivalent to Array.indexOf?

For example -

```
var array:Array = ['one','two'];
trace(array.indexOf('two')); // returns 1, since it's at the second position
trace(array.indexOf('three')); // returns -1, since it isn't found
```

... right? but what if I've got this -

```
var xml:XML = <list><item>one</item><item>two</item><list>
var xmlList:XMLList = list.item;
```

there's got to be an easier way to check to see if one of the nodes in the XMLList has a particular value than looping through all of them, right? something akin to -

```
xmlList.indexOfChildByNodeValue('two'); // returns 1, because it's the second child
xmlList.indexOfChildByNodeValue('three'); // returns -1, because it doesn't match any children
```

make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put together a demo of how you can do it without looping. Though it does call for a little more upfront work. Though it pays off if you are going to be checking values a lot.

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete="_init();">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XML id="movieList" source="http://www.movies.com/rss-feeds/jen-yamato-reviews-rss" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.logging.ILogger;
            import mx.logging.Log;
            import mx.logging.LogEventLevel;
            import mx.logging.targets.TraceTarget;

            public static const MOVIE_TITLE:String = "Inception";

            private var _logger:ILogger = Log.getLogger("Sandbox");

            private function _init() :void
            {
                var traceTarget:TraceTarget = new TraceTarget();
                traceTarget.level = LogEventLevel.ALL;
                Log.addTarget(traceTarget);

                var xmlList:XMLList = movieList..item;

                var firstItem:XML = movieList..item[0];
                var firstItemIndex:int = firstItem.childIndex();
                _logger.info("First Item Index: " + firstItemIndex);

                var item:XML = xmlList.(title == MOVIE_TITLE)[0];
                _logger.info("Contains: " + xmlList.contains(item) + " // " + item.childIndex());

                var actualIndex:int = (item.childIndex() - firstItemIndex);
                _logger.info("Actual Index: " + actualIndex);

                _logger.info("Result: " + xmlList[actualIndex]);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

The basic idea is that you store the index of the first `item` and then subtract that from the `childIndex()` of the matched result using E4X search.

Comment: Wow, overachiever! I figured there was some cool way to do it with E4X  - so the meat of your example is "movieList..item.(title == 'MovieTitle')" right? That works because each item node has a title node - in my case, imagine the item nodes contain nothing but the movie titles as a node value. would that end up looking like... "movieList..(item == 'MovieTitle')"?

Comment: In you example it will be: xmlList.(toString()=="one")

Comment: @matt-lohkamp - haha, thanks. I like to verify my answer is correct in a sandbox before posting it here. Patrick is correct with how to do it using your example. I personally would use `    text()` rather than `    toString()` though. Check out the documentation and decide for yourself what best suites your needs though.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the only bet is to loop through the XMLList.  The other option you have is to use: [contains()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XMLList.html#contains%28%29)  Though this will only help in your situation if you actually only want to know whether `indexOf() == || != -1`.

I am not sure of how the XMLList is actually stored in the underlying C++, but if it truly is just an array, then a linear search O(n) is the best you are going to do.

Comment: I'm sure a linear search it's what's essentially going on under the hood for Array.indexOf, so yeah, you're probably right. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way of actually writing that line of code. I looked at XMLList.contains(), but that matches XML nodes, and in this situation I only know the node's text value (which is XML.toString()), not the value of the other attributes - I'm guessing that function wants an exact match, not just a match on the node value.

thanks!